# How to re-add a removed tab in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs3, extjs4.2

I want to add/remove a tab.

I am aware of add/remove methods. But my issue is that I want to re-add the same tab, again. The re-added tab is stored in memory. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
function addMyTab(tab) {
    var me = this;
    if (!tab) { // use most recently added tab
        tab = me.tab;
    } else { // update most recently added tab
        me.tab = tab;
    }

    var tabPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(..);
    tabPanel.removeAll();
    tabPanel.add(me.tab);
}
```

This however doesnot work, it throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCls' of null

An [Extjs forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192670-Problem-with-destroying-component) suggest that this is due to trying to add an already destroyed element.

How can re-use the tab?

Comment: What is `tab` here, and are you sure it is what you think it is at the time you call `tabPanel.add`?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer tab is a Ext.panel.Panel. There is no reason for it to change, at least in my code.

Comment: Have you tried `remove` with the `autoDestroy` param specifically set to false?  Surely you're not really trying to re-add an actual Panel, because you wouldn't get that error if that were true, right?

Comment: really confusing question, needs more code.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer setting `autoDestroy` to `false` did the trick. Thanks! If you'd like to add an answer.

Comment: Glad to help... I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be saying you're re-adding the same panel that you are removing, I'm guessing that the panel is being destroyed after the removal step.  Something like this should work I think:

```
// initially add the panel
tabPanel.add(myPanel);

// remove it with autoDestroy set to false so Ext doesn't kill your panel
tabPanel.removeAll(false); 

// re-add the panel
tabPanel.add(myPanel);
```

Comment: @Is7aq Make sure you call `Ext.destroy()` on the tabs you won't be reusing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
var currentTab = null;
function addMyTab(tab) {
    var me = this;
    if (tab) { // use most recently added tab
        currentTab = tab;
    } 
    var tabPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(..);
    tabPanel.removeAll();
    tabPanel.add(currentTab );
}
```

currentTab  is a global variable . If you pass a new tab to update the current tab , replace the current tab with the new tab it , otherwise use the current tab as it is. Make sure that before using currentTab the first time , to initialize it with some tab.